# flowgorithm uninitialized variable

Tags: flowgorithm

I am a beginner in programming. I am making a flowgorithm for my programming class. But I keep getting an uninitialized variable. The uninitialized variable is "Speedy"

```
Set selectSnail = selectSnail(Speedy, Zippy, Slick, leaveRaces, snailName)
```

Why is it uninitialized?

Answer (score 0):

A variable in Flowgorithm and many other languages has to be Declared and then Assign to it some value.

In Flowgorithm you should go to the section before calling selectSnail and declare (and assign) some value to Speedy